# IntelliJ - Formatting Java code in Markdown

Tags: java, intellij-idea, markdown

When a Java code snippet is added to Markdown, the indentation is not formatted correctly. For example, having the following code snippet:

````
```java
if(x==0){
    if(flag){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```
````

will render the following once the auto-formatter is complete

````
```java
if(x==0){
        if(flag){
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
        }
```
````

I am certain that this is a part of the language of Java's settings because replacing ```` ```java ```` with just ```` ``` ```` will keep the format as usual.

How can I ensure to have IntelliJ format Java code snippets appropriately in Markdown (or ignore autoformat and I would format them myself)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that partial code snippets are not supported yet. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267081

As a workaround, uncheck the **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Markdown | Inject languages in code fences** option:
[image]

Comment: Wow! I missed that. Thank you for this :).